# Drupal logo is displayed with out the dimensions like width and height

Tags: 7

My client raised an issue that when viewing the source the logo of my website does not have any attributes, but I saw many themes, and not all have those attributes.

How do I add these to the logo? Is it really required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The width and height is [not required](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/objects.html#edef-IMG) when using the `img` tag, but you can add it by overriding the theme template for the page, aka page.tpl.php in the directory containing the theme for your site. Usually sites/.../themes/YOURTHEME

Comment: It's not required but it's consider good practice to include them to avoid your page being resized during DOM rendering (Google mentions to [specify image dimensions](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/rendering.html#SpecifyImageDimensions)). Here's the relevant Drupal.org [issue](http://drupal.org/node/1012416).